# How to get the chapter title seperate part content

Tags: chapters

I want to get the chapter title contents,

I know \thechapter is chapter number, \chaptername stand for "Chapter", now I want to get the real title text, so, anyone give me some advice, thanks.

I want to quote the title contents in somewhere.

[image]

Comment: The title is what you input.  The other stuff is auto generated.  What do you need it for?

Comment: @Johannes_B I want to quote the title in somewhere.

Comment: You would need to save the content in a helper macro, but that depends on the class and maybe used packages. Impossible to say any more detailed. Or maybe look at `cleveref` and friends.

Comment: @zongxian: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @zongxian  Do you have a problem with my answer? If not please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `nameref` package (and `\label`).

```
\documentclass{book}% or other regular class
\usepackage{nameref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap title}\label{chap}
\section{Sec title}\label{sec}
This is section titled \nameref{sec} in chapter titled \nameref{chap}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It run perfectly.